# Texture mapping in LWJGL

Tags: animation, sprite, lwjgl

This have been driving me crazy for the past couple of days.

I'm animating a spritesheet, and it actually works out fine on my 96px 384px texture with this code:

```
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f((frameCount*24.0f)/imgWidth, (row*24.0f)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(0+x, 0+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
        glTexCoord2f((frameCount*24.0f)/imgWidth, ((row+1)*24.0f)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(0+x, 32+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
        glTexCoord2f(((frameCount+1)*24.0f)/imgWidth, ((row+1)*24.0f)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(32+x, 32+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
        glTexCoord2f(((frameCount+1)*24.0f)/imgWidth, (row*24.0f)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(32+x, 0+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
    glEnd();
```

Problem is though, that when I load in a 32px 32px texture, it looks weird! I suspect that the number 24.0f should be different according to the texture size, but I can't figure out how.

Second question: How does this method affect the performance, are there better ways of doing it?

Comment: Actually, I solved it with:

  texture.bind();
  
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glTexCoord2f(32.0f*frameCount/imgWidth, 32.0f*row/imgHeight); glVertex3f(0+x, 0+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
   glTexCoord2f(32.0f*frameCount/imgWidth, 32.0f*(row+1)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(0+x, 32+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
   glTexCoord2f(32.0f*(frameCount+1)/imgWidth, 32.0f*(row+1)/imgHeight); glVertex3f(32+x, 32+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
   glTexCoord2f(32.0f*(frameCount+1)/imgWidth, 32.0f*row/imgHeight); glVertex3f(32+x, 0+y, -0.001f*(y+32));
  glEnd();

But still wanna know, is this efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The texture coordinate for the **x-axis** (width or **u** value) should be:

```
frameCount * (frameWidth / imgWidth)
```

with frameWidth being the width of each frame in your texture and imgWidth being the total width of the texture.

The texture coordinate for the **y-axis** (height or **v** value) should be:

```
frameCount * (frameHeight / imgHeight)
```

with frameHeight being the height of each frame in your texture and imgHeight being the total height of the texture (in this case they are probably the same since each frame texture has same height as the entire texture here - or that's what I'm assuming by looking at your code).

If you want the code to be more efficient, you can precompute the multiplications that happen multiple times for each quad. So you can probably precompute:

```
float widthFraction = frameWidth / imgWidth;
float heightFraction = frameHeight / imgHeight;
```

The same applies for the vertex coordinate calculations, by the way.

**Over hundreds of thousands of vertices**, this will definitely speed the computations up a bit, but you should compare the two methods to see how much.